# react-native android release Environmental Science

Tags: react-native

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. 
Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
```

Answer (score 0):

add packages.json
  "bundle-android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res"